# $wpdb -> get_col returns duplicated arrays

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to get all the values for all sessions under the "session_value" column in the "wp_woocommerce_sessions" DB table.

The following code does the job but for some reason is duplicating the result 6 times, giving me 6 arrays with the exact same content.

```
global $wpdb;
$wooSessions = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT session_value FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_sessions" );
$wooCookies = implode(" ", $wooSessions);
```

I'm reading about OBJECT_K in the documentation which in theory discards duplicated keys but I don't know how to apply it. If I add OBJECT_K inside the get_col parenthesis the code stops working.

This is the output var_dump ($wooSessions); is giving me:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(4366) "a:12:{s:4:"cart";s:2084:"a:2:{s:32:"1b4cfd194c804d1ad422a350aa2a0145…"}

array(1) { [0]=> string(4366) "a:12:{s:4:"cart";s:2084:"a:2:{s:32:"1b4cfd194c804d1ad422a350aa2a0145…"}

array(1) { [0]=> string(4366) "a:12:{s:4:"cart";s:2084:"a:2:{s:32:"1b4cfd194c804d1ad422a350aa2a0145…"}

array(1) { [0]=> string(4366) "a:12:{s:4:"cart";s:2084:"a:2:{s:32:"1b4cfd194c804d1ad422a350aa2a0145…"}

array(1) { [0]=> string(4366) "a:12:{s:4:"cart";s:2084:"a:2:{s:32:"1b4cfd194c804d1ad422a350aa2a0145…"}

array(1) { [0]=> string(4366) "a:12:{s:4:"cart";s:2084:"a:2:{s:32:"1b4cfd194c804d1ad422a350aa2a0145…"}
```

Here's another example using session_id and session_key:

```
global $wpdb;
$wooSessions = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT DISTINCT session_id, session_key FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_sessions GROUP BY session_key" );
```

Which returns the following:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [session_id] => 2149 [session_key] => 76f0552cff4af84e1963815c1fc4a14d ) ) 
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [session_id] => 2149 [session_key] => 76f0552cff4af84e1963815c1fc4a14d ) ) 
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [session_id] => 2149 [session_key] => 76f0552cff4af84e1963815c1fc4a14d ) ) 
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [session_id] => 2149 [session_key] => 76f0552cff4af84e1963815c1fc4a14d ) ) 
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [session_id] => 2149 [session_key] => 76f0552cff4af84e1963815c1fc4a14d ) ) 
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [session_id] => 2149 [session_key] => 76f0552cff4af84e1963815c1fc4a14d ) )
```

Here's another example selecting session_id and group by session_id:

```
global $wpdb;
$wooSessions = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT session_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_sessions GROUP BY session_id" );
```

This is the result:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [session_id] => 2149 ) )
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [session_id] => 2149 ) )
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [session_id] => 2149 ) )
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [session_id] => 2149 ) )
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [session_id] => 2149 ) )
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [session_id] => 2149 ) )
```

Any ideas that can point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried `SELECT DISTINCT`

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Yes I already tried SELECT DISTINCT but nothing happens.

Comment: @cale_b I've tried adding GROUP BY session_value at the end of the query but it didn't work, I'm still getting 6 duplicated arrays.

Comment: @cale_b I've updated my question as requested. Thank you

Comment: @cale_b I just tried var_export($wooSessions); and the output is exactly the same repeated array. I even ran a find and replace in case I was missing something but all 6 arrays had the exactly the same content.

Comment: @cale_b You mean GROUP BY session_id at the end of my query? I tried that with $wpdb->get_results but I'm still getting duplicated arrays.

Comment: @cale_b I had already tried that but still get duplicated results, I've updated my question with a new example. Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Great, now we're making progress.  What do you get if you use the `SELECT session_id, session_value..... GROUP BY session_id`...?

Comment: @cale_b SELECT session_id, session_value..... GROUP BY session_id gives me the exactly same array repeated 6 times as before.

Comment: Well, something is wrong with the DB then.  `GROUP BY` would cause ONLY unique session_id's to be returned, and if it is returning multiple results with the same ID, then the DB is letting you down.  However, to be totally clear / accurate, it would be useful to see the question updated with the _exact_ query you are using, and the _exact_ results it is generating.

Comment: Thank you @cale_b, I'm lost here as I can't figure out what's happening. What can be possibly wrong with the DB? Looking at the DB on phpMyAdmin everything looks normal, neither the table or rows are duplicated.

Comment: Hi @cale_b, I truly appreciate your help. Running the same query in phpMyAdmin for session_id works fine however using session_value gives me this "Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available."

Comment: @cale_b No duplicated session ID's, also tried with session_keys column and returns unique session_keys but when I try with session_value column I get "Current selection does not contain a unique column". Any clues?

Comment: So, immediately after you run the `$wpdb->get_results()` line, add `var_dump($wpdb->last_query);` and see what it outputs?  And post that here, as well as try _that_ query in phpMyAdmin, and let me know the results?

Comment: Big thanks @cale_b for putting me in the right direction, var_dump($wpdb->last_query); outputs the same query repeated 6 times which showed me the problem wasn't the DB but my code, so I realised the real issue was that I had this $wpdb request inside a foreach() construct. This problem has been solved thanks to you.